# Choice function from an element to a set

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $X$ with a topology $T$. The following holds for $A$: For every $x\in A$ there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U\subseteq A$.

Is it possible to construct a function $f:A\to B$ where $B=\{U\in T : U\subseteq A \}$.

Comment: Yes, it is. For each $x$ we have to choose some $U_x$ such that $x\in U_x\subset A$.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It is always possible to construct *a* function. I'm assuming you want $f(a)$ to be an open neighborhood of $a$. But this is also trivial, take the interior of $A$ (which is non-empty by the assumption) and the constant function. So perhaps you want an injective function from $A$ into $B$, which will finally put some nontriviality on the whole story.

Comment: @zap: Since this is tagged with the [axiom-of-choice] tag, I'd imagine that "construct" somehow means without appealing to the axiom of choice. Sans the caveats that I pointed in my previous comment, which trivializes this entirely, it is possible to construct counterexamples to an injective choice function like that.

Comment: Well, it is quite obvious. Notice that $A$ is neccessarily open (is a neighborhood of all its points). We could put $f(x):=A$ for all $x\in A$. I mean $A\in B$.

Comment: @zap: I noticed that, but it was too late to edit my comment, so I posted an answer with some additional information as to why the axiom of choice is somewhat necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Since neither $A$ nor $B$ are empty, it is always possible to construct *a* function. Fix some $U\in B$ and define $f(a)=U$ for all $a\in A$. But by the given condition, it seems that you want to somehow argue that $f(a)$ will be an open neighborhood of $a$, this is also easy, since the condition you give implies that $A$ is in fact open, so $f(a)=A$ is a suitable function.

If you want something a bit less trivial, then additional constraints are in order, for example, the function has to be injective. In that case, additional assumptions on the topology and the axiom of choice are necessary (e.g. if $T$ is the trivial topology, and $A$ contains more than one point, this is impossible).

Let me give an example where the axiom of choice actually plays a role. Suppose that there exists a subset of $\Bbb R$ which is infinite and Dedekind-finite, namely $D\subseteq\Bbb R$ is infinite but has no countably infinite subset. We may also assume that $D$ is dense, or at least unbounded.

Fix an enumeration of the rational numbers $\{q_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ and define the following topology on the natural numbers: $U$ is open if and only if there is some $r\in D$ such that $U=\{n\mid q_n<r\}$, or if $U\in\{\varnothing,\Bbb N\}$. It is easy to verify two things:

1. This is a topology.
2. The topology itself is Dedekind-finite. Namely, there is a bijection between the open sets and $D\cup\{\varnothing,\Bbb N\}$.

Take $A=\Bbb N$ itself, if we want an injective choice function for open sets, then in particular it would mean there is a countably infinite set of open sets in the topology. But this is not the case, so this is impossible. Therefore any choice function has to have finitely many values.

Comment: The topology defined on $\Bbb N$ is not even $T_0$, though. One could try and take $D$ as the topological space with the subspace topology, but this is a futile attempt since then we can just take $f(a)=(a-1,a+1)\cap D$ as the open set, and it is easy to see that this will be an injective choice function. It is interesting to ask whether or not a Hausdorff, or at least $T_1$ or $T_0$ spaces will have such function. Although I'd imagine that the answer is most likely negative.